# Return a value from coroutine inside of an SDK (without blocking the main thread)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm porting an SDK to Kotlin, that is basically a wrapper for some network calls. The existing Java version uses callbacks to return the results to the developer. From what I have understood, coroutines seemed to be a reasonable approach to implement this, but I'm struggling at the point of how to return the result without blocking the main thread.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public void onClickButton(View v) {

    OiSDK oiSDK = new OiSDK(new NetworkHandler());
    List<Token> tokens = oiSDK.getTokens();    
}
```

OiSDK.kt

```
fun getTokens() = runBlocking {

        Log.d("OiSDK", "getTokens - from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        val tokens = async { fetchTokensFromServer() }.await()
        tokens        
}

suspend fun fetchTokensFromServer(): List<Token> {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("OiSDK", "fetchTokensFromServer - from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    var tokens = ArrayList<Token>()

    val response = networkHandler.networkAPI.authorize(registrationUri,
            authorizationHeader, Constants.TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
            code, redirectUrl)

    tokens.add(new Token(response))

    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("OiSDK", "Time taken: ${endTime - startTime}")

    return  tokens
}
```

Log trace:

```
2020-03-08 22:18:24.741 11740-11740/D/MainActivity: Update progessBar 14 - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:24.844 11740-11740/D/MainActivity: Update progessBar 15 - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:24.945 11740-11740/D/MainActivity: Update progessBar 16 - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:25.143 11740-11740/D/OiSDK: getTokens - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:25.150 11740-11818/D/OiSDK: fetchTokensFromServer - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:28.202 11740-11740/D/OiSDK: Time taken: 3058
2020-03-08 22:18:28.217 11740-11740/D/MainActivity: Update progessBar 17 - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:28.228 11740-11740/D/MainActivity: Update progessBar 18 - from thread main
2020-03-08 22:18:28.320 11740-11740/D/MainActivity: Update progessBar 19 - from thread main
```

Couple of issues:

1. `runBlocking` blocks the main thread (as described in several places, incl. the docs).
2. Using a scope (e.g. `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch`) will use a worker thread for the network call instead, but `getTokens` still blocks the main thread.
3. If I use any scope with `launch`, I don't know how to return the result.

Are coroutines actually suitable for this use case, as I don't just want to update some UI, but need to return something outside of the scope of the SDK? If so: how can that be achieved?

Comment: To avoid blocking, the caller must be inside a coroutine already. You can't make `fun getTokens: List<Token>` not block the thread.